# npm UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY warnings when installing angular2

Tags: npm, warnings

I am having strange **UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY** warnings when installing angular2. I have tried cache cleaning and have all dependency installed as shown below but still getting the warnings:

[image: dependency warnings]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you rewrite your package.json as below as same warning i was getting and rewritting package.json solved it :

```
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 requires a peer of es6-shim@^0.35.0 but none was installed.
```

package.json: "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",

```
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 requires a peer of reflect-metadata@0.1.2
```

package.json: "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",

```
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0beta.6
```

package.json: "rxjs": "5.0.0beta.6",

```
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 requires a peer of zone.js@0.6.12
```

package.json: "zone.js": "0.6.12",

```
Delete node_modules directory

npm install
```